# Akka Streams: Outlet not available when upstream closes in my Sliding window implementation

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

I have implemented a sliding window which starts on a trigger. Have written test code to test my sliding window stage using the Akka Streams TestKit.

My test is not completing and control doesn't come out of while loop in onUpstreamFinish method. I see this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AssertionError: assertion failed: timeout (3 seconds) during expectMsg while waiting for OnNext(Stream(12, ?))
    at scala.Predef$.assert(Predef.scala:219)
    at akka.testkit.TestKitBase.expectMsg_internal(TestKit.scala:401)
    at akka.testkit.TestKitBase.expectMsg(TestKit.scala:378)
    at akka.testkit.TestKitBase.expectMsg$(TestKit.scala:378)
    at akka.testkit.TestKit.expectMsg(TestKit.scala:890)
    at akka.stream.testkit.TestSubscriber$ManualProbe.expectNext(StreamTestKit.scala:337)
    at com.glassbeam.scalar.lcp.rules.timeseries.SlidingWindowOnTriggerTest2$.delayedEndpoint$com$glassbeam$scalar$lcp$rules$timeseries$SlidingWindowOnTriggerTest2$1(WindowTest.scala:122)
    at com.glassbeam.scalar.lcp.rules.timeseries.SlidingWindowOnTriggerTest2$delayedInit$body.apply(WindowTest.scala:95)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.Function0.apply$mcV$sp$(Function0.scala:34)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
    at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
    at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:389)
    at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
    at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
    at com.glassbeam.scalar.lcp.rules.timeseries.SlidingWindowOnTriggerTest2$.main(WindowTest.scala:95)
    at com.glassbeam.scalar.lcp.rules.timeseries.SlidingWindowOnTriggerTest2.main(WindowTest.scala)
```

Have googled outlet being unavailable but couldn't get satisfactory results.

Akka, Akka Streams, Akka Streams TestKit version: 2.5.9
Scala version: 2.12.4

SlidingWindow:

```
case class SlidingOnTrigger[T](duration: Duration, trigger: T => Boolean, collector: T => Boolean, timeEpochExtractor: T => Long) extends GraphStage[FlowShape[T, collection.Seq[T]]] {


  val in = Inlet[T]("TriggeredSliding.in")
  val out = Outlet[collection.Seq[T]]("TriggeredSliding.out")
  override val shape: FlowShape[T, collection.Seq[T]] = FlowShape(in, out)

  override protected val initialAttributes: Attributes = Attributes.name("sliding")


  override def createLogic(inheritedAttributes: Attributes): GraphStageLogic = new GraphStageLogic(shape) with InHandler with OutHandler {
    private var inPursuit = Vector.empty[mutable.MutableList[T]]

    private val bufSeq = mutable.Queue.empty[collection.Seq[T]]

    var watermark = -1L

    private def untilDoneIndex(current: T) = {
      inPursuit.indexWhere { buf =>
        if (buf.nonEmpty) {
          val hts = timeEpochExtractor(buf.head)
          val cts = timeEpochExtractor(current)

          cts >= hts + duration.toMillis
        } else false
      }

    }


    override def onPush(): Unit = {
      val data = grab(in)

      val timeStamp = timeEpochExtractor(data)

      if (timeStamp > watermark) {
        watermark = timeStamp

        if (trigger(data)) {
          inPursuit :+= mutable.MutableList.empty[T]
        }

        val indexUntilDone = untilDoneIndex(data)

        inPursuit.indices.foreach { i =>
          if (i <= indexUntilDone) {
            bufSeq.enqueue(inPursuit(i))
          } else {
            if (collector(data)) {
              inPursuit(i) += data
            }
          }
        }

        inPursuit = inPursuit.drop(indexUntilDone + 1)
        pull(in)

      } else {
        pull(in)
      }

      checkAndPush()
    }

     private def checkAndPush() = {
      if (bufSeq.nonEmpty && isAvailable(out)) {
        push(out, bufSeq.dequeue())
      }else if(isClosed(in) && inPursuit.nonEmpty && isAvailable(out)){
        push(out, inPursuit.head)
        inPursuit = inPursuit.drop(1)
      }

      if(isClosed(in) && bufSeq.isEmpty && inPursuit.isEmpty){
        completeStage()
      }
    }

    override def onPull(): Unit = {
      if (!isClosed(in) && !hasBeenPulled(in) && bufSeq.isEmpty) {
        pull(in)
      } else {
        checkAndPush()
      }
    }


    override def onUpstreamFinish(): Unit = {

    }

    this.setHandlers(in, out, this)
  }

}
```

Test Code:

```
object SlidingWindowOnTriggerTest extends App {

  import akka.actor.ActorSystem
  import akka.stream.ActorMaterializer
  import akka.stream.scaladsl.{Keep, Sink, Source}
  import scala.concurrent.duration._

  implicit val as = ActorSystem("WindowTest")
  implicit val m = ActorMaterializer()

  val expectedResultStream = Stream.from(0).map(_.toLong)

  val testIt = Iterator.from(0).take(20).map(_.toLong)

  val (_, ts) = Source
    .fromIterator(() => testIt)
    .via(SlidingOnTrigger[Long](10 millis, x => x % 3 == 0, _ => true, identity))
    .toMat(TestSink.probe[Seq[Long]])(Keep.both)
    .run()

  ts
    .request(10)
    .expectNext(expectedResultStream.take(10))
    .expectNext(expectedResultStream.take(13).drop(3))
    .expectNext(expectedResultStream.take(16).drop(6))
    .expectNext(expectedResultStream.take(19).drop(9))
    .request(10)
    .expectNext(expectedResultStream.take(20).drop(12))
    .expectNext(expectedResultStream.take(20).drop(15))
    .expectNext(expectedResultStream.take(20).drop(18))
    .expectComplete()

  as.terminate()

}
```

Also, provide any suggestions to make implementation better

Comment: @johanandren have updated the code. I did the changes as suggested but still the same result. `onUpstreamFinish` doesn't complete and have included `isClosed(in)` checks. For the other part, I did not get what switching to different `OutHandler` meant

Comment: You can at any point replace the in and out handlers with a new call to setHandler(in/out, handler), so for different states you can have separate handlers, in some cases that makes the GraphStage simpler.

I'd recommend testing different scenarios with the probes in the stream testkit to figure out what is wrong with your GraphStage implementation.

Answer (score 0):

There is a case when downstream has not signaled any demand but upstream completes. Given that you have your own buffers you need to deal with having elements in them if this happens.

The solution in place which will block in with a never-completing while loops in `onUpstreamFinish` is not good. Even in the best case scenario you will never have more than one possible outstanding push you can do, in the worst case scenario you are blocking a thread forever.

What you need to do is to not complete the stage if there are things in the buffers when `onUpstreamFinish` is invoked but instead make sure the remaining elements can be pulled. This can be done in two ways, either by having such a check in pull (can be done with `isClosed(in)`) or by switching to a different `OutHandler` that only feeds the downstream from the buffer until empty and then completes.

Comment: I did include another `request(10)` call, to request more. But no help